# how to listen to tweets loaded dynamically in twitter?

Tags: javascript, dom, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add an image to every tweet in my timeline by building a chrome plugin. Currently the plugin works for tweets loaded when the page is refreshed. But how do i extend the plugin to include the "new tweets" and the "past tweets" which are dynamically loaded in my timeline?

Comment: I am attempting to solve the same problem it looks like you found a solution below would you mind posting a code sample of what worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for them periodically using `setInterval()` or search if there is any event that is called by Twitter script after pulling tweets.

There are also [some events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) that look relevant, but I did not test them, eg.:

- `DOMNodeInserted` - fires when a node has been added as a child of another node,

**EDIT:**

I see that **Twitter uses jQuery**. jQuery in turn has [`jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) function **that is called before AJAX request is being made**. You can probably use it to bind your event to the `jqXHR` object (which is `XMLHttpRequest` object, I suppose) and do different things depending on what it will return. See [the documentation of `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) and [the documentation on `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: I tried DOMNodeInserted and it doesnt seem to work.. setInterval() I havent tried, will do it now..

Comment: @user926321: `setInterval()` should work, but for instant checks you can use the solution I have just inserted into my answer. It uses `jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()`, that you can use to intercept the response from the server (I suppose, I haven't tried it within Google Chrome extension) and if Twitter responds with new tweets, you can simply execute your script, inserting an image for every new tweet (after it is inserted into the HTML, so you do not interfere with how Twitter's script work).

Comment: Actually setInterval() works clubbed with the right condition statements works very well for me! .. will try the other suggestion later! Thanks!