# How to execute JavaScript in Chrome extension every time twitter feed loads?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know how to tell my JavaScript Chrome extension to execute every time a user scrolls down and a new set of tweets is loaded? It must be some "execute onload" command, but I'm really inexperienced with JavaScript (and Chrome extension building). Right now, my little script is this:

```
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByClassName("tweet");
myNodelist[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

I just want to execute this every time a new set of tweets is loaded.

Comment: there are several questions already answered that are similar under chrome extension, search them.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818995/how-to-listen-to-tweets-loaded-dynamically-in-twitter?rq=1